# Kibana Painless Scripted Fields

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I'm new to Kibana. I've been tasked with replicating an excel report into a dashboard.

I want to use a data table to display my values and also have a calculated field for percentages.
The percentiles metric is not what I am trying to use to perform my calculations.

In the excel report the percentages are calculated using a formula like this :
=I20/$I$28*100

It's a relatively simple formula I want to replicate in Kibana. Is there a way to create a scripted field in Painless or is there an even easier way to do this?

Some assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
return 100 * doc['SD_TOTAL'].value / 81857
```